# Pentaho with Oracle data masking - Timestamp issue

Tags: oracle, datetime, pentaho

I'm using Pentaho to datamask some of the information on the oracle DB

I have several transformations of the form:
SELECT -> data mask -> UPDATE rows based on primary key

I have tables where a timestamp is part of the primary key in the update step. Even though I am not masking or updating this field in any way, I get the error ORA-01843: not a valid month when performing the update.

I believe this is because when Pentaho takes in the timestamp from Step 1 it doesn’t actually keep it as a timestamp until I try the update and hence the primary key check. Outputting to excel, I see pentaho giving timestamps in the format

2014-07-30 15:44:31.869033 Europe/London (Pentaho)

But in DB the format is

30-JAN-15 09.21.38.109145000 AM (Oracle - TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE)

I have tried to convert the pentaho field to a Timestamp (format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS) before the update step but receive errors if I try and use milliseconds.

2017/03/14 13:19:25 - Select values.0 - AUDIT_CREATE_TS Timestamp : couldn't convert string [2015-01-30 09:21:38.109145 Europe/London] to a timestamp, expecting format [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ffffff]

2017/03/14 13:19:25 - Select values.0 - Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

If I replace my formatting to the one suggested by Pentaho I get "Illegal character 'f'" and then I am stuck in a loop.

Ignoring milliseconds seems to succeed but won’t give me any matches because it isn’t precise enough and returns no results from db..

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Pentaho, but if you're looking for a conversion from this string:

```
'2015-01-30 09:21:38.109145 Europe/London'
```

to a timestamp with timezone in Oracle, it would be:

```
select to_timestamp_tz('2015-01-30 09:21:38.109145 Europe/London', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6 TZR') from dual;
```

See Oracle [Datetime Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) document for more.